# C : Create a function to diplay number just with "write" function

Tags: c, unistd.h

How can I write a basic function using just the `write` function declared in `#include <unistd.h>`, in order to display a number?

example:

**ft_putnbr.c**:

```
int ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{
    write(1, &nbr, sizeof(int));
    return (0);
}

int ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
    return (0);
}
```

**main.c**:

```
int     ft_putnbr(int nbr);
int     ft_putchar(char c);

int     main(void)
{
    ft_putnbr(6);
    ft_putchar('\n');
    ft_putchar('a');
    return (0);
}
```

The function `ft_putchar` works fine, but I would like to do the same with a number, with my `ft_putnbr` function.

There is no error when I'm compiling or executing the code, but a blank is displayed instead of my number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i use this one:

```
void        ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{
    if (nbr < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');
        ft_putnbr(-nbr);
    }
    else if (nbr > 9)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nbr / 10);
        ft_putnbr(nbr % 10);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putchar(nbr + '0');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the `int` to a `char*` representation (ASCII translation). For example:

```
int nbr = 1234;
char str[16]; /* max size expected: 15 digits + 1 null character */
sprintf(str, "%d", nbr);
```

and then:

```
write(1, str, strlen(str));
```

Yo need to include these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: 15 digits? 32-bit integers have 10 digits(+sign) 64-bit integers have 20 digits (+sign). I guess the average is 15 :p

Comment: it's just an example, he can adjust to his needs

Answer (score 1):

this one also checks for int_min and int_max

```
void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb == -2147483648)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');
        ft_putchar('2');
        ft_putnbr(147483648);
    }
    else if (nb < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');
        ft_putnbr(-nb);
    }
    else if (nb > 9)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nb / 10);
        ft_putnbr(nb % 10);
    }
    else
        ft_putchar(nb + '0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Library `putnbr()`**
We don't have any similar function in Public Library, we just use `printf`.

**`ft_putnbr`**
This function will display the integer `n` on the standard output. It is similar to `ft_itoa` function because we will be doing it recursively.
We will be breaking down `int` number as a whole, into individual single digit numbers, and we will convert those `int` numbers into characters.

That we will display on the standard output using our `ft_putchar` function.

So the function doesn't need to return any value, but needs a number for accomplishing its task.

We will declare the function like this:

```c
void ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{

}
```

In function's body, we start by seeing if the `int` passed in parameter is equal to **-2147483648**.

**2147483648**, is the largest number an `int` variable can possibly hold. When a negative sign is placed in front of it, our function is not able to handle it, so we check to see if a negative version has been given, and if so we just immediately return it.

```c
void ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{
    if (nbr == -2147483648)
    {
        ft_putstr("-2147483648");
    }
}
```

So, if `nbr` is not equal to **-2147483648**, we will check another condition if `nbr` is a negative number, if it is, we will immediately use `ft_putchar(-)` to display the minus to the standard output, and will call `ft_putnbr()` again on a negative version of the variable `n`.

In Mathematics `-(-5) = 5`, so the number is made positive using this method:

```c
void ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{
    if (nbr == -2147483648)
    {
        ft_putstr("-2147483648");
    }
    else if (nbr < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar();
        ft_putnbr(-nbr);
    }
}
```

If our given number is not negative, we will move to the next `else if`, and we will check to see if the number is greater than or equal to 10. If it is, we begin to break down the number recursively to each individual digit, where we will then convert it into a character.

Meaning, we will be going to use a division by 10, and a modulus by 10. The division by 10 will take us further into the recursion until we finally reach the very first number in our int.

If you look at the modulus 10, we use a `+ 48` to convert the number into a char value. Though, this seems like it will be put to the standard output immediately, it will actually happen last since it will be the last thing to happen when we backtrack out of our recursion.

We will use `ft_putchar` on this digit to display it on the standard output, and then back track through our recursion until every individual digit has been displayed.

```c
void ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{
    if (nbr == -2147483648)
    {
        ft_putstr("-2147483648");
    }
    else if (nbr < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar();
        ft_putnbr(-nbr);
    }
    else if (nbr >= 10)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nbr / 10);
        ft_putchar(nbr % 10 + 48);
    }
    else 
    {
        ft_putchar(nbr + 48);
    }
}
```

**Remark:**
if you have any difficulty understanding recursion, you should write out the steps this function will take on a piece of paper.

- [GFG - Recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/)
- [GFG - Recursive function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/)

Complete code:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{
    if (nbr == -2147483648)
    {
        ft_putstr("-2147483648");
    }
    else if (nbr < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar();
        ft_putnbr(-nbr);
    }
    else if (nbr >= 10)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nbr / 10);
        ft_putchar(nbr % 10 + '0');
    }
    else 
    {
        ft_putchar(nbr + '0');
    }
}
```

For testing my code, I will use this simple main function:

```c
int main ()
{
    int a = 555;
    ft_putnbr(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursion:

```c
//recursion solution:
void    ft_putnbr_fd(int n, int fd)
{
    long int    nb;
    char        c; //place holder for write();

    if (fd < 0)
        return ;
    nb = n;
    if (nb < 0)
    {
        nb *= -1;
        if (!write(fd, "-",1))
            return ;
    }
    if (nb < 10)
    {
        c = nb + '0';
        if (!write(fd, &c, 1))
            return ;
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putnbr_fd(nb / 10, fd);
        c = nb % 10 + '0';
        if (!write(fd, &c, 1))
            return ;
    }
}
```

however, in my opinion a more elegant, simpler way is by using a `for()` or `while()` loop:

```c
//while loop solution:
void    ft_putnbr_fd(int n, int fd)
{
    long    ln;
    long    divider;
    char    c;

    if (fd < 0)
        return ;
    ln = n;
    if (ln < 0)
    {
        if (!write(fd, "-", 1))
            return ;
        ln = ln * -1;
    }
    divider = 1;
    while (divider * 10 <= ln)
        divider = divider * 10;
    while (divider)
    {
        c = ln / divider + '0';
        if (!write(fd, &c, 1))
            return ;
        ln = ln % divider;
        divider = divider / 10;
    }
}
```

As you see both solutions require only the `write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbyte)` function from <unistd.h>. The while loop solution, by removing the first while loop, it will also print leading 0's. hope this helps!

2023/04/14:
Also, for unsigned integers, this might be interesting to look at. Writing nbr in any base provided to stdout. If base is higher than strlen(basestr) it won't write anything.

Usage: writing "420" in decimal(base 10): `ft_putuint_base(420, 10, "0123456789");`

```c
void    ft_putuint_base(unsigned int nbr, int base, char *basestr)
{
    unsigned long   divider;
    int             baselen;

    baselen = 0;
    while (basestr && basestr[baselen])
        baselen++; //equivalent of `baselen = strlen(basestr);` but no segfault.
    if (base < 2 || baselen < base) //proper error check
        return ;
    divider = 1;
    while (divider && divider*base <= nbr)
        divider = divider * base; //for usage example, this will execute twice
    while (divider) // 420/100 -> write(basestr[4]); and 20/10 -> write(basestr[2]); and 0/1 -> write(basestr[0]); becomes "420";
    {
        if(!write(1, &basestr[nbr / divider], 1))
            return ;
        nbr = nbr % divider;
        divider = divider / base;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion is always more elegant, iteration is often more practical :-)

Comment: begs the question if you see somewhere where you could use it, should you?
computers are so blazingly fast that I think I'll prefer readability over performance.